# Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for [c] in [/WEB-INF/jsp/report/TestArchive.jsp]

Tags: jsp, tomcat

The same JSP works fine when the application is deployed on weblogic 12 but when deployed on tomcat, i am getting **"Illegal child tag in "core:choose" tag: "displaytag:column" tag**

849: Illegal "displaytag:column" after "core:otherwise" tag in "core:choose" tag"

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Below is the block of code where i am getting this error.

```
                                    <core:choose>
                                        <core:when test="${command.notFoundTest}">
                                            <displaytag:column headerClass="c" class="c" title="<input type='checkbox'  name = 'selectAllTest' id ='selectAllTest' onclick='checkUnCheckTest()'> " >
                                                <core:choose>
                                                    <core:when test="${!command.logInTest || (command.logInTest && detailsBean.childRuleTest eq '<%=MyConstants.ADMIN_RULE_NUM%>')}">
                                                        <spring-form:checkbox path="selectedArrayTest" value="${counter}" onclick="return selectCheckBox();" />
                                                    </core:when>
                                                    <core:otherwise>
                                                        <spring-form:checkbox path="selectedArrayTest" value="${counter}" onclick="return selectCheckBox();" disabled="true"/>
                                                    </core:otherwise>
                                                </core:choose>
                                            </displaytag:column>
                                        </core:when>
                                        <core:otherwise>
                                            <core:choose>
                                                <core:when test="${command.missingDetails}">
                                                    <displaytag:column class="hidden" headerClass="hidden" titleKey="grid.select" >
                                                        <input type="radio" id="radioButton" name="radioButton" onclick="radioCheck('${counter}');" />
                                                    </displaytag:column>
                                                </core:when>
                                                <core:otherwise>
                                                    <displaytag:column headerClass="c" class="c" titleKey="grid.select" >
                                                        <core:choose>
                                                            <core:when test="${!command.logInTest || (command.logInTest && detailsBean.childRuleTest eq '<%=MyConstants.ADMIN_RULE_NUM%>')}">
                                                                <input type="radio" id="radioButton" name="radioButton" onclick="radioCheck('${counter}');" />
                                                            </core:when>
                                                            <core:otherwise>
                                                                <input type="radio" id="radioButton" name="radioButton" onclick="radioCheck('${counter}');" disabled="disabled" />
                                                            </core:otherwise>
                                                        </core:choose>
                                                        
                                                    </displaytag:column>                                                    
                                                </core:otherwise>
                                            </core:choose>
                                        </core:otherwise>
                                    </core:choose>
```